# Adding two RecylcerViews in same Layout under eachother

Tags: android

I want to add two horizontal RecylclerViews under each other. This is the code I write,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this layout there is only one RecylcerView displayed. How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your android_manifest.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weight_sum="2"  
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view2"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear layout with weight or you can also go for ScrollView with

Try setting the property fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView.

Answer (score -1):

try this adding weight and setting the height to fill_parent will make it work

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view2"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```